# Herencia de atributos en Java

Tags: java, poo, herencia, atributos

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación Java en la que se cuenta con una clase `AnimalesCompania`, de la que heredan varias subclases como `Perro`, `Gato`, `Hamster`...

Cada una de estas subclases lleva asociado un multiplicador. La aplicación sirve para el cobro de impuestos, por lo que según el animal de compañía, el multiplicador variará y la cantidad a pagar será diferente.

Veamos por ejemplo el caso particular para la clase `Gato`:

```
public class Gato extends AnimalesCompania
{
    private final static double MULT_GATO=1.4;
    
    public double getMult(){
        return MULT_GATO;
    }
}
```

Puesto que el multiplicador nos va a hacer falta más adelante he supuesto que lo más adecuado sería incluir un método que nos lo devuelva. Ahora bien, ya que todos los animales tienen un multiplicador, y todos ellos van a necesitar el método `getMult()`, ¿podría implementarlo de alguna manera en la clase padre `AnimalesCompania`? Y, puesto que todos tienen un atributo `MULT`podría declararlo también en la clase padre `AnimalesCompania`, y que siga siendo diferente para cada tipo concreto de animal?

Por si sirve de algo la implementación de la clase `AnimalesCompania` por ahora:

```
public class AnimalesCompania extends Propiedad{
    
    private int EdadAnimal; //en meses
}
```

Posee un único atributo `EdadAnimal`, pero que me plantea el mismo problema, ya que necesito que sea distinto para cada instancia, y no sé si es mejor declararlo en la clase base `AnimalesCompania` o si es preferible declararla en cada animal por separado, por ejemplo dentro de la clase gato aparecería como `EdadGato`.

Comment: dale una revisada a lo que es un metodo [abstracto](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=668:clases-y-metodos-abstractos-en-java-abstract-class-clases-del-api-ejemplos-codigo-y-ejercicios-cu00695b&catid=68&Itemid=188) con respecto al atributo edad es mejor declararlo en la clase padre y mediante su constructor heredarlo a las sub clases es mas si las subclases tienen el atributo MULT tambien puede ser heredado de la clase padre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes declararlo en tu clase `AnimalCompania` como un atributo, que lo puedes inicializar también en el constructor, y en cada subclase le pasarías al `super(1.4, edad)`, en este caso 1.4 que es el valor que tienes puesto. Y también tendrías en esta clase el método `getMult()`

clase `AnimalCompania`

```
public class AnimalCompania extends Propiedad{
    
    protected double mult;
    protected int edadAnimal;

    public AnimalCompania(double mult, int edadAnimal){
        this.mult = mult;
        this.edadAnimal = edadAnimal;
    }

    public double getMult(){
        return mult;
    }

    public int getEdadAnimal(){
        return edadAnimal;
    }
}
```

clase `Gato`

```
public class Gato extends AnimalesCompania{
    
    public Gato(int edad){
        super(1.4, edad)
    }
}
```